# How can I disallow deleting text from input?

Tags: html

How I can disallow deleting text from input?

```html
<div class="card starter">
  <div class="head">
    Green-transparent
  </div>
  <div class="ticket">
    <input type="text" class="card-input" name="myvalue" id="myvalue" value="+reticle_color '-255 -255 -255'">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <button onclick="copyToClipboard()" class="btn">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) may be useful in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer.

Now if you have a form that you will submit then use

> readonly

instead of

> disabled

.

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myvalue");


  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="card starter">
  <div class="head">
    Green-transparent
  </div>
  <div class="ticket">
    <input disabled type="text" class="card-input" name="myvalue" id="myvalue" value="TEST">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <button onclick="copyToClipboard()" class="btn">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have the button for copy, but with disable it not works

Comment: @Kodziru you then have a problem with your copy function. Check my answer.